# expand div to entire screen

Tags: html, css

I have searched this for the last 30 minutes, and I have tried every solution including VH, setting HTML/Body's width to 100%, but for some reason it just doesn't work for me.

If you view the image: http://gyazo.com/a4df21fa35dda0805e344ba9d22b30be

It doesn't expand to the entire screen for some reason. Why is there even a horizontal scroll in the bottom of my screen?

```
<style>
body {
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/jzI8yai.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
html {
width: 100%;
}
.bar {

background: #003366;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;

}


</style>

<body>
<div class="pictures">
</div>

<div class="bar">

Hello

</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following style

```
html, body {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `margin:0` to the body element:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.

That's one of the reason why people using [Normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) or a [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to start a new project. Another approach to avoid not desirable results can be something like:

```
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Wow.. I had no idea that the default margin was 8px. Thank you very much, I will be sure to use the rest css to start a new project.